# xaxis populated with weekdays looping

Tags: highcharts

wasted lot of hours searching up and down, but didnt found my very simple needing.
I just only need xaxis showing: (weekdays rolling looping repeating)
Mon tue wed thu wed sat sun Mon tue wed thu wed sat sun Mon tue wed thu wed sat sun Mon tue wed thu wed sat sun ....... repeating or looping the 7 days till infinite (Y has a value).
This should be very easy to make, should be 1st chapter in the first demo lines but No Way, noone treat the simple.
Thank YOU in advance
Best regards
eng G. Bono from Italy Turin.

Answer (score 0):

For a categorized axis you can for example programmatically create an array with weekdays, for example:

```
var data = [...],
  categories = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'wed', 'sat', 'sun'],
  i = 7;

for (; i < data.length; i++) {
  categories.push(categories[i - 7]);
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: data
  }],
  xAxis: {
    categories: categories
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4962/

---

For a datetime axis you need to only use the proper format:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a', this.value)
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4963/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter